# Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name

Tags: r

Without opening any files, I get the following error when opening Rstudio:

> "Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name"

All my commands are ignored (i.e. nothing happens, no warnings and R becomes unresponsive to anything I do) and I have tried rm and gc options to no availability and also updated to the latest version of Rstudio and R but I still get this error.

I am running windows 7 (64bit).

Comment: What OS? What R and RStudio versions (be explicit)? Have you set up a `.Rprofile` file to automatically run code on startup? How exactly are the commands ignored? Do you see a prompt at the console?

Answer (score 10):

I've posted an issue on [dplyr github page](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1576). I can reproduce the results using the code below. It has to do with whether the csv contains a column of rownames without a header. `read_csv` and `read.csv` handle this differently, thus producing differing results with `filter`.

***First the case when it works***

`write_csv` to `read_csv` or `read.csv`; both work fine with `filter`

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% write_csv("~/Desktop/test.csv")
test_r <-  read_csv("~/Desktop/test.csv") %>% filter(hp>100)
test.r <-  read.csv("~/Desktop/test.csv") %>% filter(hp>100)
```

***Now for when it fails***

When csv is generated through a process like `write.csv`, unless the person changes the default of `row.names` to `FALSE`, it introduces a column of rownames w/o a header. When reading the data back in, `read_csv` does not fill in the header where the rownames are, but `read.csv` imputes an X. Thus, when `filter` works on `read.csv` imports, it has all headers with filled cells, but `filter` after `read_csv` has an empty header cell at least where rownames are.

The following code should error after `test1_r %>% filter(hp>100)` with the following error

```
Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) : 
  attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

Again, the big difference is how write.csv produces the csv.

```
mtcars %>% write.csv("~/Desktop/test1.csv")


test1_r <- read_csv("~/Desktop/test1.csv")
test1_r %>% str() 
#should fail here
test1_r %>% filter(hp>100)


test1.r <- read.csv("~/Desktop/test1.csv")
test1.r %>% str() 
test1.r %>% filter(hp>100)
```

To solve the problem, you can use `read.csv` as mentioned above by @hackR. Or you can subset out the first column when you know the csv behaves like this:

```
test1_r <- read_csv("~/Desktop/test1.csv")[-1]
```

Or, if you are in control of the csv-creation step, you can add the option `row.names=FALSE` to `write.csv`

```
mtcars %>% write.csv("~/Desktop/test2.csv", row.names = FALSE)
test2.r <- read_csv("~/Desktop/test2.csv")
test2.r %>% str() 
test2.r%>% filter(hp>100)
```

or use `write_csv` as shown above.

Comment: @skeletonnoire, did this address your problem?

Comment: This can also just happen if your .csv has a column without a header.

Comment: @data_steve Thanks , read_csv works for me as initially i am using read.csv to read my file which cause this error too.

Answer (score 4):

Putting this as an answer for visibility: this happens if you try to run by selecting all in the Rmd and pressing enter like you would with a normal R script. RStudio tries to run this all as R code, including the markdown parts, leading to the errors you saw.

You can avoid this by running an individual chunk by clicking the green play button or by selecting one of the run options in the dropdown at the top of the Rmd editor.

`Try run all from RUN dropdown`

Comment: I should probably turn this into a self-answered question, but I had exactly this happen recently without actually running more than a code chunk. Turns out RStudio has some issues with wide unicode characters, which made it think the code chunk included the ``` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message and it was related to read_csv() from Hadley's readr package. If I did this:

```
cyt <- read_csv(fil)
cyt2 <- cyt %>% filter(EPID == 10030001)
```

then I got the error message "Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) :  attempt to use zero-length variable name".  But if I used the analogous base read.csv() function then it worked OK.

```
cyt <- read.csv(fil, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
cyt2 <- cyt %>% filter(EPID == 10030001)
```

I think this may be a bug in read_csv(), or perhaps I am misusing read_csv().

---

In your specific case, perhaps something is running automatically when you are loading RStudio.

Comment: I have the same exact problem and replacing with read.csv solved it.

Comment: I have exact same problem